# SSRS BIDS Error when executing oracle query (This command is not supported by this provider)

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I am creating a SSRS report which directly gets the data from oracle.

When i run this query in the "query designer" then i am getting an error saying

"This Command is not supported by this provider".

I had tried using 'Oracle' and 'OLEDB' connection types but they didn't worked.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Please advise me on this

Comment: I've seen this before, but my first suggestion would have been to try the different connection types.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a SQL Command? what is the SQL? Does the SQL run directly against Oracle (i.e. in TOAD or SQLPLUS)

Comment: I am running an oracle query (PL SQL) against oracle from microsoft bids while creating a ssrs report.

Comment: Have you tried running that Oracle query directly against Oracle without SSRS (i.e. in SQL Developer which comes free with Oracle)? This will isolate whether the issue is with your query or with your client library.

Comment: Also do you have any other Oracle queries working? Do you have the Oracle client installed on the machine that you are running BIDS on? Can you connect to Oracle using SQLPLUS.EXE?

Comment: Hi, i tried to run it in the toad and it worked there. Other oracle queries are working fine.I can able to connect to oracle and executed this problematic oracle query successfully.